# ADmob - Problemas com Anuncios em APP

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Fiz tudo como manda o tutorial do site do ADMOB,  coloquei o layout no XML, importei o path do Google Play Sevices e adicionei as linhas de código do tutorial, meu aplicativo compila, mas não abre mais no smartphone, aparece uma mensagem de alerat dizendo que o app parou e no log do Eclipse aparece a seguinte mensagem (abaixo), preciso de um help.

[image: Erro ao executar o app]

Mensagem no Eclipse:

```
05-26 10:47:02.007: E/AndroidRuntime(9092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{your.CalculoHE.namespace/your.CalculoHE.namespace.CalculoHoraExtraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Classe:

```
package your.CalculoHE.namespace;


import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class CalculoHoraExtraActivity extends DroidGap {    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.sobreaviso);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);

        // Consultar o AdView como um recurso e carregar uma solicitaÃ§Ã£o.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    }    
   }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6560993155721972/3382486845"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hora extras"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.CalculoHE.namespace"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name=".CalculoHoraExtraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>


    </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Não Math, estou utilizando o appframework da Intel

Comment: não entendo do assunto, desculpa, vou passar a bola :)

Comment: Poderia informar a linha do NullPointer? É a linha: `adView.loadAd(adRequest);`?

Comment: @Wakim, é esta linha mesmo!          adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Comment: @Wakim aparece esta mensagem de erro com o construtor The constructor AdRequest() is undefined, Eu não sei como resolver isso!

Comment: Esta usando o ANT ou Gradle pra fazer o build do app? Este tipo de mensagem ocorre quando a classe não esta no classpath.

Comment: @PauloRoberto não use o construtor default do `AdRequest`, ele é privado. Use o builder...

Comment: @Wakim estou utilizando o ANT sim, cara ja estou boiando nisso ai, to quase desistindo...Se nem seguindo o tutorial do site o negocio da certo.

Comment: Olhando seu código, está igual ao meu, o problema é em relação ao Layout, pq parece que ele não está achando o AdsView (usando o findViewById). O problema está no layout, tem que ver se o DroidGap não está impedindo seu layout, ja que você carrega um html depois né...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olhei o código da DroidGap no repositório do [Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android). E pelo que entendi, não é possível fazer da forma que você fez, incluindo um layout android seu com a AdsView, porque ele sempre sobreescreve o layout.

Você terá que seguir por esse caminho:

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import com.google.ads.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    private static final String AdMob_Ad_Unit = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AdMob_Ad_Unit); 
        LinearLayout layout = super.root; 
        layout.addView(adView); 
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

        // Comment this out before publishing.
        // request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        adView.loadAd(request); 
    }
}
```

Outra sugestão é, apesar do tutorial usar a `DroidGap`, use a `CordovaActivity` pois a `DroidGap` esta marcada como `@Deprecated`.

Existe um tutorial no [codetheory](http://codetheory.in/admob-native-android-sdk-integration-with-phonegap-cordova-without-plugins/), que irá te ajudar a incluir Ads no seu app.

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Se der certo, marque como correto :P